# Nested loops/ASCII?

Tags: java, loops

So, for an assignment in my computer science class, we've got to use loops, either for or while, depending on preference. Now, the assignment IS to use said loops and a given input to draw a beauteous ASCII diamond made of '$' and '-'. Say, an input of 5 would look like:

```
____$
___$-$
__$-$-$
_$-$-$-$
$-$-$-$-$
_$-$-$-$
__$-$-$
___$-$
____$
```

The underscores are to denote spaces. Now, anytime I try using

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input a number between three and ten here: ");
double length=Double.parseDouble(input);
int i=0; int j=0;
for(i=1; i<length; i++)
    {
  System.out.print(" ");
  for(j=1; j<=i; j++)
    {
    if(j<i){System.out.print("-$");
    }
   else if(j==i){System.out.println("");}
    }
                                       }
```

I come out with something like, say, for input=7:

```
-$
-$-$
-$-$-$
-$-$-$-$
-$-$-$-$-$
```

And yes, the two too few in the center is true with any input. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your homework, I'm just going to point you towards the correct answer and leave you to figure out the rest. Let's try formatting your code so you can see what's going on:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Input a number between three and ten here: ");
double length=Double.parseDouble(input);
int i=0; int j=0;
for(i=1; i<length; i++){
    System.out.print(" ");
    for(j=1; j<=i; j++){
      if(j<i){
        System.out.print("-$");
      }
      else if(j==i){System.out.println("");
    }
  }
}
```

Now, you've got an outer loop for i ranging from 1..length-1, and for each i you're going to print a space, then you're going to count from 1 to 1 and print "-$" that many times. Then, you're going to print a newline and repeat the outer loop, incrementing i

So, the first time through the outer loop, you print one space, followed by one "-$", followed by a newline. Then on the second time through the outer loop, you print one space, followed by "-$" twice, followed by a newline. And so forth, until i=length, and then you stop.

You want to print a few more spaces before you print dollar signs - a loop here will probably be useful.

Answer (score -1):

try to go trough this code and see how it works... it might be useful for your homework

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input a number");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    input.close();

    boolean add = true;
    int counter = 0;
    do {
        if (add) {
            counter++;
            print(' ', number - counter);
            print('$', counter);
            if (counter == number)
                add = false;
            System.out.println();
        } else {
            counter--;
            if (counter == 0)
                break;
            print(' ', number - counter);
            print('$', counter);
            System.out.println();
        }

    } while (true);
}

private static void print(char c, int times) {
    if (c == '$')
        times = (times * 2) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        System.out.print(c);
}
```

if you edit the print method you will get your desired result

```
private static void print(char c, int times) {
    if (c == '$')
        times = (times * 2) - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
        if (i % 2 == 1 && c == '$')
            System.out.print('-');
        else
            System.out.print(c);
}
```